# Swift 3 iOS 10 Reference to UIImageView to get Value for other function

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiimageview, ios10

I'm looking for a way to add codewise a way to reference to a UIImageView's value from another function.

I'm having a function which creates a new UIImageView for each instance in an array. Moreover, it also has an UITapGestureRecognizer added which calls a function when tapped. Now I want the function, which is called upon tap, to get the instance of that array which relates to the respective UIImageView.

I hope it's clear what I want to do. :)

Comment: you can create unique id for each UIImageView and you write single function for Tap. Depending on the id, the corresponding UIImageView Gets tapped.

Comment: So when you tap on the UIImageView you want the tap gesture recogniser to tell you which array the image view is in? Or do you want to know which UIImageView has been tapped?

Comment: So instead of using the UITapGestureRecognizer writing a seperate function for the tap. But what would this function look like?

Comment: @WsCandy the idea is to have each an icon for each instance in the array. The UIImageView is not connected in anyway to the array. That's why I want to give the UIImageViews some kinda ID for being able to refert to the position in the array that UIImageView is corresponding to.

Comment: If the source images are in an array that the called function can access, why not just set the array index as the *tag* property in each image view?

Comment: That's what I tried actually. I set the .tag upon creation of the imageview but i can't get the value when I'm calling the function when tapped.

Comment: See my answer - you just need one line of code in the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have an array of images:

```
let myImages = [UIImage(named: "image1"), UIImage(named: image2", UIImage(named: "image3"0]
```

And you have these images in three separate image views:

imageViewA.image = myImages[0]
   imageViewB.image = myImages[1]
   imageViewC.image = myImages[2]

Also, you've set up everything correctly that each image view calls the same function on a tap (we'll call it `imageViewTapped()`).

All you need to do is (1) properly set the tag property of each image view to point at the array index, (2) get the view that was tapped on, and (3) retrieve the image.

```
imageViewA.tag = 0
imageViewB.tag = 1
imageViewC.tag = 2

func imageViewTapped(_ recognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let tappedView = recognizer.view
    let sourceImage = myImages[tappedView.tag]
}
```

I'd recommend setting everything up in a loop (tags, tap recognizer) and adding some type-casting in the function if needed. But I can't see your code to help you with that.

Comment: PERFECT! Tactually i already had the

func imageViewTapped(_ recognizer:UITapRecognizer) {
    let tappedView = recognizer.view
    let sourceImage = myImages[tappedView.tag]
}
but instead of casting UITapGeastureRecognizer I had AnyObject. This must've been the reason because it returend nil.